# Python AppEngine coding for Android app?

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine

I'm a newbie **Android Developer**, and my app requires that it interacts with a server.

I came across **Google AppEngine**, and find it to be a good choice for this app.

If I code my Android app in Java, and do the server coding for Google AppEngine in **Python**, will my Android App be able to communicate with the server?

I mean will this Java (client) + Python (server) combination work well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The communication with your server can be totally independent of the languages used on the server and client end.

Typically web applications use principles such as **REST** to communicate. This is why your browser runs using HTML and JavaScript and your server can be using anything, including python.

It really depends on what you need your server to do for your app.